# Conversion failed string to int when using RAISERROR

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to use RAISERROR instead of print in my stored procedure to avoid the known lag of PRINT statement.

Here is how I was using it

```
DECLARE @s varchar(100) = 'sfsdf'
RAISERROR('Deleted %s ', @s, 0, 1) with nowait
```

But it's triggering an error

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'sfsdf' to data type int.

I don't understand what I did wrong

Comment: A quick look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) would tell you the issue. The 2nd parameter for `RAISERROR` is the [severity level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-error-severities?view=sql-server-ver15), and that is a numerical value. `'sfsdf'` isn't a valid severity level.

Comment: Though the documentation also states: *"The RAISERROR statement does not honor SET XACT_ABORT. New applications should use THROW instead of RAISERROR."* You should really be using `THROW`.

Comment: @Larnu THROW does not have a severity level, it can't be used as replacement for PRINT, it's always error

Comment: `THROW` isn't a "replacement" for `PRINT` at all, @NenadZivkovic ...

Comment: @Larnu - that was Nenad's point. They are using `raiserror` as an alternative to `print` with string interpolation and no buffering (`nowait`) if they hadn't muddled the parameters it would be a severity 0 message so info not error  `DECLARE @s varchar(100) = 'sfsdf'
RAISERROR('Deleted %s ', 0, 1, @s) with nowait` so the suggestion to use `throw` is not applicable

Answer (score 1):

To bring conclusions from comments to the actual answer...

It's just that the parameters are not in order.

As per [RAISERROR Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) - 2nd parameter is severity level - number not string, and @s argument should come at the end:

So correct use would be:

```
DECLARE @s varchar(100) = 'sfsdf'
RAISERROR('Deleted %s ', 0, 1, @s) WITH NOWAIT
```